# On process termination which happens first? Child processes and tasks deletion or calling of atexit functions?

Tags: linux, unix, process, linux-kernel

I want to know that when a process terminates normally, which of the following happens first:

1. Child processes termination.
2. Calling of cleanup functions registered using atexit.

Comment: This post should belongs to unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without special code written in the process, the `atexit()` function will run first. The kernel will consider the children only on final program termination, depending on further circumstances it might then terminate the children.